# How to find the first integer point cartesian plan intersection of the line joining origin and another point?

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I have a cartesian plane as shown in the following image:

[image]

I want to find out given a point `(x,y)`, what is the first point with integer coordinates lies in the line joining `(0,0)` and `(x, y)`.

What is an efficient approach to answer the above question?

Currently, I am just going iterating x from `[1, x]` by incrementing it by `+1` and checking if `y = x * tan(phi)` is an integer, where `phi` is in polar for point `(x,y)`.

But the above approach seems very slow for large `x`. Is there a better approach to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: consider the gcd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d try proving the following: if a non-vertical line passes through $(a,b)$ (where $a,b\in Z$), then the integer points the line passes through are precisely those of the form $(ma’,mb’)$ where $m \in Z$, and $a’ = a/\gcd(a,b)$, and $b’ = b/\gcd(a,b)$.

It will follow that the ‘first point’ (by which I think you mean the closest point to the origin in the first quadrant) will be $(a’,b’)$.

Comment: got it. Thanks.